# Install python dev package without yum

Tags: python, sybase, virtualenv

I'm currently trying to install a few modules via `virtualenv`, which I have bootstrapped at the moment, and so far `pip` and `easy_install` have been working fine. I am now trying to install the [Sybase](http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/index.html) module; however, it seems I need `gcc` to install it as I'm getting the following output:

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
copying Sybase.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
running build_ext
building 'sybasect' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6
gcc ...
unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

I am now trying to install the python dev package which I'm assuming will solve my problem; however, I don't have network access from the command line and can't use `yum install`. Is there a way to install the python dev package from a `tar.gz` or some other method? or just  `gcc` for `virtualenv`? My machine does not have a native `gcc` either and I can't get it at this stage.

Comment: If you can't get gcc to work, could you build on a local pc and transfer the binaries? (Assuming same OS etc)

Comment: I have gcc on my local machine, but via cygwin, so not the same OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing `python-dev` will not solve your problem as you miss GNU C compiler on your system.
Installing that one, will probably fix your issue. `python-dev` is a secondary and missing that one will result in different type of errors (namely missing headers during compilation process).

And.. if you can't get native gcc, I'm afraid you're out of luck at this point.

Comment: But still, any ways to install python-dev from source?